# VSCODE for golang

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I have been using VSCode for programming in Golang and sometimes GoLand trial version. I want to stick with VSCode but I cannot find the below-mentioned capabilities in VSCode. Can anyone tell me if it is possible or not

- There is no way for me to have a pop-up displaying the list of all  functions, structs, interfaces in the file that I have open?
- Is there a way to click on an interface and see the list of all implementers?
- Is there a way to click on a struct and see the list of all interfaces it implements?

GoLand has all of these and that is what makes it amazing. Other than that most of the things are similar.

Comment: Seems not: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/go - why not stick with what works?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, I am still contemplating whether to buy goland as I have the trial version only

Answer (score 10):

Actually it is possible to do all three things in VS Code as well.

**1. List of all functions, structs, interface - Code Outline**

There is a great extension [Code Outline](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=patrys.vscode-code-outline) that works very well with Go code. I'm using it successfully without any problems.

[image: Code outline]

**2. Is there a way to click on an interface and see who all implement it?**

According to VS Code [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_go-to-implementation), it is possible to go to definition using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> shortcut. It seems to work well for Go source code at this point.

[image: Interface to implementation]

**3. Is there a way to click on a struct and see what all interfaces it implements?**

Similarly as with answer above, and according to documentation, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> shortcut seems to be working well in that case.

> For an interface, this shows all the implementors of that interface
>   and for abstract methods, this shows all concrete implementations of
>   that method.

[image: Implementation to interface]

Comment: it says plugin is deprecated now. Says use VS provided plugin or sth. Does that all the capabilities you mention? How do I install this plugin otherwise?

Comment: For the last point, it does the opposite of what is asked (shows structs implementing an interface, not interfaces implemented by a struct).

Comment: @curiousengineer you're right. The extension seems to be deprecated now, I haven't noticed it, just found right now. However, native Code Outline view seems to be working the same way, you can enable it here: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_24#_outline-view Does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Just right click on interface/struct definition and select "**Go to implementations**", it will pop up an context window.

Internally it relies on `guru` which had been deprecated by golang team. Guru does not support module as well.

Newer plugin `gopls` relies on "`Language Server Protocol(LSP)`" which is actively developing by golang team, but I am not sure it has same functionality as "Go to implementations".